# Querying the number of specific items in a database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was just wondering how could I count the number of a specific equipment..

```
SELECT 
    EQUIPMENTS.DESCRIPTION AS [EQUIPMENT TYPE], 
    Count(EQUIPMENTS.EQNAME) AS QUANTITY,
    (SELECT Count(EQUIPMENTS.CONDITION) FROM EQUIPMENTS WHERE EQUIPMENTS.CONDITION = 'Functional') AS WORKING,
    (SELECT Count(EQUIPMENTS.CONDITION) FROM EQUIPMENTS WHERE EQUIPMENTS.CONDITION = 'Non-Functional') AS [NON-WORKING]
FROM EQUIPMENTS
GROUP BY EQUIPMENTS.DESCRIPTION;
```

this query returns the following :

```
EQUIPMENT NAME : PROJECTOR
QUANTITY : 3
WORKING : 2
NON-WORKING :1
```

Now if I add another equipment which has a different type, for example CALCULATOR, it would have the same count of WORKING AND NON-WORKING which only is for the PROJECTOR. How do I Make it such that it also counts the quantity of the Calculator and the number of working and non-working itself? I mean whenever I add another equipment which has a specific description, the query would also count it independently?

I'm using VB.NET and this query is made in MS ACCESS 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IIf()` expressions to return 1 when the condition is satisfied, and 0 when not.  Then `Sum` those values.

```
SELECT 
    e.DESCRIPTION AS [EQUIPMENT TYPE], 
    Count(e.EQNAME) AS QUANTITY,
    Sum(IIf(e.CONDITION = 'Functional', 1, 0)) AS WORKING,
    Sum(IIf(e.CONDITION = 'Non-Functional', 1, 0)) AS [NON-WORKING]
FROM EQUIPMENTS AS e
GROUP BY e.DESCRIPTION;
```

Comment: I have a question, as I was transferring this query to the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard in VB.Net, there appears a notice.

Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text

what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't know VB.Net, so I've no clue why it would complain about that SQL.